# Create a comments template for custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, theme-options

Is it possible to create a comment template for custom post types? I want the wording for comments on a custom post type to be different for wording on a regular wordpress post.

I tried comments-posttype.php but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Could you please go back and actually work on your old questions (comment, comment, comment!). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the single template of the custom post type i.e. "single-posttype.php" (create one if it doesn't exist). In the function `comments_template()` the first parameter represents the filename, so make it `comments_template('/comments_file_name.php');`

Reference- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template